# How to translucent only one fragment

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

I use single activity architecture and navigation component.
I want to translucent only my splash fragment
by changing style all fragment are changed
Setting fitSystemWindows true in splash fragment not work
:(

[Like this sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLkW.jpg)

please help me

Comment: you can check from `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener` if its splash or other fragment. and change statusbar accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must follow these steps:

1- Add lines below inner your style theme

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

2- Add this property `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to root element of fragments that you don't want to make them translucent